# How do I get the counter to output the hidden code if I try to subtract from zero?

Tags: java

My assignment said to include an override of the default constructor that sets the counter to zero and a constructor that allows you to set the count. I realize there is a lot of code in here but I am a noob. Sorry for adding stuff that is 'fluff'.

```java
public class TestHarnessAssignment2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Counter c1 = new Counter(), c2 = new Counter();

        // comment about things that will print
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Initial State");
        System.out.println("counter1" + c1);
        System.out.println("counter2" + c2);
        System.out.println("Counter1 equals Counter2 " + c1.equals((c2)));

        /*
         * c2.subtract1(); c2.subtract1();
         * 
         * System.out.println(); System.out.println(
         * "Error - Attempted to subtract 1 Widget from 0 Widgets.");
         * System.out.println("Number of widgets reset to 0");
         * System.out.println();
         */
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter in a number to increment the count by");
        c1.addToCount();
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("State after the first test.");
        System.out.println("counter1" + c1);
        System.out.println("counter2" + c2);
        System.out.println("counter1 does not equal counter2 " + c1.equals(c2));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter in a number to decrement the count by");
        c1.subtractFromCount();
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Please enter in a number to increment the count by");
        System.out.println("Thank you!");
        System.out.println();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("State after the second test.");
        System.out.println("counter1" + c1);
        System.out.println("counter2" + c2);
        System.out.println("counter1 equals counter2 " + c1.equals(c2));

    }
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Counter {
    // private state variable
    private int counter1;

    // default constructor
    public Counter() {
        counter1 = 0;
    }

    // user arbitrary mutator
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void addToCount() {
        setCounter1(getCounter1() + input.nextInt());
    }

    // user abitarity mutator 2
    public void subtractFromCount() {
        setCounter1(getCounter1() - input.nextInt());
    }

    // user abi
    // mutator
    public void setCounter1(int newCount) {
        counter1 = newCount;
    }

    // accessor
    public int getCounter1() {
        return counter1;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return " is at " + counter1;
    }

    // sets smamitches
    public int smamitches() {
        return counter1;
    }

    // comment
    public boolean equals(Counter s) {
        return smamitches() == s.smamitches();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code and improve the indention. Your IDE should help you. Also please reduce your code to what is necessary for a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: A piece of advice, don't add direct input/output logic in a class meant to be called externally.  In other words, main should contain an instance of `Scanner`, not `Counter`.  If you really need to put such logic in a class, dedicate a class to just that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public Counter() {
    counter1 = 0;
    }
```

in the Counter-Class is your Constructor. You can just have a 2nd one with adding

```
public Counter(int i){
//Do wathever you like
}
```

In this 2nd constructor you can also set your fields in different way as in the other one. like counter1 can be assigned to any value you like. This is called overload. you might search for it on the internet. it's essential for learning programming.